# smtp StartTLS office 365 (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, smtp, starttls

I have a problem regarding mail going to the junk folder. I have found a lot of smtp plugins that support SSL and TLS but non that fully support StartTLS. Is there a plugin that I've missed or how would I solve this problem without a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this question is 6 months old at the time of this writing, with 209 views. Glad I know I'm not the only one with this problem!

Anyway I found a solution - **use the plugin called WP Mail SMTP** (by WPForms) https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

I have a client using Office365 and their StartTLS was not having it with the Easy WP SMTP or Cimy plugins. Not sure what WP Mail SMTP is doing differently but it works, I'm gonna check out their code to see what the other plugins are missing.